# Selecting frequent values from multiple columns from R table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` `res` which has data as follows:

```
            V1 V2 V3 V4
  1:     Day_1  4  4  4
  2:     Day_2  1  1  2
  3:     Day_3  4  5  4
  4:     Day_4  3  4  4
  5:     Day_5  3  2  3
```

I need to select the most frequent value from the columns V2, V3 and V4 combined. That is, I need to select result as follows:

```
Day_1 4
Day_2 1
Day_3 4
Day_4 4
Day_5 3
```

I'm not expecting any ties since the there will be always odd number of columns. Is it possible to manipulate the `data.table` to do this? Or should I modify it some other data type?

Thanks - V

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode) is the function you looking for probably.

Comment: Try `apply(res[,-1, with=FALSE], 1, Mode)` `(Mode)`from the link

Comment: the use of Mode (from the link) with the apply statement works perfectly well! Thank you.

Comment: @akrun I would try `DT[, .(res = Mode(unlist(.SD))), by = V1]` instead.

Comment: @DavidArenburg You could post that as an answer.

Comment: How about `dt[V2 == V3 | V2 == V4, ans := V2][V3 == V4, ans := V3][]`?

Comment: @Arun Given that there are no ties, I guess `dt[,ans:=V2][V2!=V3,ans:=V3]` is a little simpler.

Comment: @Frank your code gives incorrect result on OPs data.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oops, you're right; thanks. Should be `DT[,ans:=V2][V3==V4,ans:=V3]`

Comment: @Frank that's ice for 3 columns. but it will get real messed up the columns grow.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Indeed. I was just trying to simplify what Arun suggested (but I failed on the first try, whoops).

Comment: @Frank, I was hoping to distinguish the case where all three are unique, with `NA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm posting this as a `data.table` version of [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode) until something better is offered

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)  
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

DT[, .(res = Mode(unlist(.SD))), by = V1]

#       V1 res
# 1: Day_1   4
# 2: Day_2   1
# 3: Day_3   4
# 4: Day_4   4
# 5: Day_5   3
```

Comment: @David...thank you. I will wait for a little while longer before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two variations on David's answer:

```
# table
DT[,ans:={
    tab <- table( r = rep(.I,length(.SD)), unlist(.SD) )
    as( colnames(tab)[ max.col(tab) ], class(.SD[[1]]) )
},.SDcols=-1]

# apply Mode
DT[,ans:=apply(.SD,1,Mode),.SDcols=-1]
```

I thought I'd take a look at these because splitting `DT` by row might be slow.

**Speed**.

*Comparison against by-row*. Starting out with very few unique values and rows...

```
n  <- 1e4
nv <- 5
nc <- 3

DT <- do.call(data.table,c(
  list(id=1:n),
  replicate(nc,sample(nv,n,replace=TRUE),simplify=FALSE)
))

require(rbenchmark)

benchmark(
  table     = DT[,.({
    tab <- table( r = rep(.I,length(.SD)), unlist(.SD) )
    as( colnames(tab)[ max.col(tab) ], class(.SD[[1]]) )
  }),.SDcols=-1],
  byMode    = DT[,.(Mode(unlist(.SD))), by = id],
  applyMode = DT[,.(apply(.SD,1,Mode)),.SDcols=-1],
  replications=10
)[1:5]
#        test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 3 applyMode           10    1.66    4.611      1.65
# 2    byMode           10    2.03    5.639      2.02
# 1     table           10    0.36    1.000      0.36
```

Increasing each of the three parameters separately...

```
nv <- 1e3 # up from 5

#        test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 3 applyMode           10    1.67    1.000      1.67
# 2    byMode           10    2.05    1.228      2.02
# 1     table           10    4.27    2.557      4.15

n  <- 5e4 # up from 1e4

#        test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 3 applyMode           10    8.67    4.492      8.65
# 2    byMode           10   10.21    5.290     10.22
# 1     table           10    1.93    1.000      1.92

nc <- 100 # up from 3

#        test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 3 applyMode           10    2.59    1.000      2.59
# 2    byMode           10    6.71    2.591      6.69
# 1     table           10   11.69    4.514     11.68
```

*Discussion*. (I'm comparing the `elapsed` columns across the benchmarks.)

- *nv.* While `table` wins for the small case, it scales poorly with the number of unique values, since its `tab` object becomes very large. The other two methods are unaffected.
- *n*. Everything scales linearly with the number of rows. (I expected `table` to scale worse on this dimension, too, but maybe `n` needs to be even larger for that.)
- *nc*. `table` scales linearly with columns as well, while the other two do better.

*Again, with melt*

```
# back to original values for n, nv, nc
benchmark(
  table     = DT[,.({
    tab <- table( r = rep(.I,length(.SD)), unlist(.SD) )
    as( colnames(tab)[ max.col(tab) ], class(.SD[[1]]) )
  }),.SDcols=-1],
  byMode    = DT[,.(Mode(unlist(.SD))), by = id],
  applyMode = DT[,.(apply(.SD,1,Mode)),.SDcols=-1],
  melt      = melt(DT, id.vars = 'id')[, .N, by = .(id, value)][, 
                value[which.max(N)], by = id],
  melto     = melt(DT, id.vars = 'id')[, .N, by = .(id, value)][
                order(N)][,last(value),by=id],
  meltMode  = melt(DT, id.vars = 'id')[,Mode(value),by=id],
  replications=10
)[1:5]
#        test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 3 applyMode           10    2.42    8.643      2.36
# 2    byMode           10    2.84   10.143      2.81
# 4      melt           10    0.28    1.000      0.28
# 6  meltMode           10    1.92    6.857      1.81
# 5     melto           10    0.44    1.571      0.44
# 1     table           10    0.83    2.964      0.81
```

Looks like @eddi's `melt` with `which.max` wins.

**Data**.

```
DT <- 
  data.table(V1=paste("Day",1:5,sep="_"),V2=c(4,1,4,3,3),V3=c(4,1,5,4,2),V4=c(4,2,4,4,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert to long form and then it's trivial to do:

```
dt <- data.table(id=paste("Day",1:5,sep="_"),V2=c(4,1,4,3,3),V3=c(4,1,5,4,2),V4=c(4,2,4,4,3))

melt(dt, id.vars = 'id')[, .N, by = .(id, value)][, value[which.max(N)], by = id]
#      id V1
#1: Day_1  4
#2: Day_2  1
#3: Day_3  4
#4: Day_4  4
#5: Day_5  3
```

This is significantly faster than the other options so far, as long as number of unique `(id,value)` pairs is not too large.